# Inconsistent Bouncy Castle ECDSA Signing/Verifying behavior on IOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, bouncycastle

## The Problem:

I expect Signing and Verifying Signatures using the same nuget package on different platforms/systems to behave in a similar fashion.

However, Signing and Verifying Signatures using BouncyCastle on an IOS system (Simulator and phone produce the same results) occasionally (and by occasionally I mean quite frequently) produces what appears to be invalid signatures.

### What I tried:

In an attempt to make sure I wasn't doing anything wrong, I wrote a short test program which would randomly generate 100 sets of data, sign each set 10000 times, and verify each signature. A pure BouncyCastle implementation of the desired behavior on Windows - and it worked, 1 million out of 1 million times.

This code also appears to work when tested on Android; again, 100% of the time.

However, when it comes to testing it on IOS, the same results cannot be replicated.

Here are the results testing on IOS (Each test round consisted of shutting down the simulator, then running the IOS program via Visual Studio. Then, the program generates a new private/public key pair and signs a random set of data bytes 10000 times):

*The testing was originally only on the IPhone XR, but I thought that it might be a problem with the specific model of phone, so I also did the test using the IPhone X. There are more results from previous testing, but they pretty much look the same as the samples listed below, even if the test was done on a physical IPhone XR.*

#### IPhone XR IOS 12.2

- Test Round 1: **10001** Signatures passed verification out of **10001?**
- Test Round 2: **10000** Signatures passed verification out of **10001?**
- Test Round 3: **10000** Signatures passed verification out of **10000**
- Test Round 4: **0** Signatures passed verification out of **10000**

*I have no idea how Test Rounds 1 & 2 came out with 10001 runs instead of 10000 - After starting the test, there was zero interaction with the process until it hit the exit breakpoint.*

#### IPhone X IOS 12.2

- Test Round 1: **9996** Signatures passed verification out of **10000**
- Test Round 2: **10000** Signatures passed verification out of **10004?**
- Test Round 3: **0** Signatures passed verification out of **10000**

*Test round 2 somehow managed to perform an extra four tests, corresponding with 4 failing tests recorded - The only thing that changed during this test was that I set a breakpoint mid loop in order to check on the progress, and then hit continue*

Additionally, we decided to check the endian-ness of both systems; what if they were mismatched? The search, however, was unfruitful, as a quick check in the immediate window of the debugger via `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` showed that both systems were using Little Endian format.

**The code used to test, modified to sign only 10000 times with one set of data**

```
static void SigningTest(byte[] data, byte[] pubkey, byte[] privkey)
{
    var curve = SecNamedCurves.GetByName("secp256r1");
    var domain = new ECDomainParameters(curve.Curve, curve.G, curve.N, curve.H);
    var d = new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(privkey);
    var xx = new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(1, pubkey.Take(32).ToArray());
    var yy = new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(1, pubkey.Skip(32).ToArray());
    var q = curve.Curve.CreatePoint(xx, yy);

    var publicParams = new ECPublicKeyParameters(q, domain);
    var privateParams = new ECPrivateKeyParameters(d, domain);

    var cipherkp = new AsymmetricCipherKeyPair(publicParams, privateParams);

    var signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA256withECDSA");
    signer.Init(true, cipherkp.Private);

    var ccount = 0;
    var icount = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        signer.BlockUpdate(data, 0, data.Length);
        var signature = signer.GenerateSignature();

        var der = Asn1Object.FromByteArray(signature) as DerSequence;

        var arrList = new List<byte[]>();

        foreach (DerInteger theInt in der)
        {
            var barr = theInt.PositiveValue.ToByteArrayUnsigned();

            if (barr.Length == 31)
            {
                barr = new byte[32];
                Array.Copy(theInt.PositiveValue.ToByteArrayUnsigned(), 0, barr, 1, 31);
            }

            arrList.Add(barr);
        }

        var realsig = new byte[64];

        Array.Copy(arrList[0], realsig, arrList[0].Length);
        Array.Copy(arrList[1], 0, realsig, arrList[0].Length, arrList[1].Length);

        if (Verify(data, pubkey, realsig))
        {
            ccount++;
        }
        else
        {
            icount++;
        }
    }
    // Add something here like System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break() so that a break point can be set.
}

static bool Verify(byte[] data, byte[] publicKey, byte[] signature)
{
    var curve = SecNamedCurves.GetByName("secp256r1");

    var x = new byte[32];
    var y = new byte[32];
    Array.Copy(publicKey, 0, x, 0, 32);
    Array.Copy(publicKey, 32, y, 0, 32);

    var derSignature = new DerSequence(
        new DerInteger(new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(1, signature.Take(32).ToArray())),
        new DerInteger(new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(1, signature.Skip(32).Take(32).ToArray()))
        )
        .GetDerEncoded();

    var xx = new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(1, publicKey.Take(32).ToArray());
    var yy = new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(1, publicKey.Skip(32).ToArray());

    var domainparams = new ECDomainParameters(curve.Curve, curve.G, curve.N, curve.H, curve.GetSeed());
    var ecp = curve.Curve.CreatePoint(xx, yy);

    var pubkeyparams = new ECPublicKeyParameters(ecp, domainparams);
    var verifier = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA256withECDSA");

    verifier.Init(false, pubkeyparams);
    verifier.BlockUpdate(data, 0, data.Length);

    return verifier.VerifySignature(derSignature);
}
```

### So, how does one go about fixing this?

Comment: "var d = new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(privkey);" should be using the signed constructor like you do everywhere else i.e. new BigInteger(1, privKey). That could explain why some rounds just fail completely. The ones with slightly-off numbers between rounds sure smells a lot like you have some kind of concurrency error unrelated to the cryptography. Not sure what to try, but maybe putting the test in non-static code (i.e. each test round is an instance of an object) would help (because not shown above is how you're collecting ccount/icount data).

Comment: I accidentally figured out why i have some slightly off numbers; it turns out if you mouse over the the `++` section of a line of code that says `variable++`, it actually adds 1 to the variable itself when you go to check. I found out when I checked the variable, and it showed 0, then checked again, and then by repeating the horizontal mouse movement I could increase the counter over and over.... I must've accidentally done that when I was collecting my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Peter Dettman pointed out, the private key was not being created using the signed version of the `BigInteger` constructor.

Along with changing that line to use the signed version of the constructor, the test code was also modified to move the initialization of the signer into the body of the for loop.

```
if (barr.Length == 31)
{
    barr = new byte[32];
    Array.Copy(theInt.PositiveValue.ToByteArrayUnsigned(), 0, barr, 1, 31);
}
```

was also changed to

```
if (barr.Length < 32)
{
    barr = new byte[32 - barr.Length].Concat(barr).ToArray();
}
```

in order to account for the fact that there is no theoretical lower limit to the byte array length of `barr`.

After these changes, the code appears to be functioning properly in all cases.